# Declarar una función en D que devuelva un tipo string

Tags: funciones, d

Sé que se puede declarar de tipo string alguna variable, pero necesito saber si las funciones en [D](https://dlang.org) pueden ser declaradas de tipo string y retornar los valores de string.

Answer (score 1):

Una función puede devolver un string.

Ejemplo:

```
string ejemplo(string texto)
{
    return "Resultado: " ~ texto;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/ZeTJfx)</kbd>